# 'require' not loading ANY file - strange error message - ruby

Tags: ruby, file, loading, require

Expected result: call on another file in the same dir with information
that will apply to current file

FILE TO BE CALLED ON:

(Location: C:\require\class.rb)

```
class Member

   @@count = 0

   def initialize
      @@count =+ 1
   end

   def self.count
      @@count
   end

end

Bob = Member.new
puts Member.count
```

OUTPUT: A new member is made, the total member count is +1

FILE DOING THE CALLING:

(Location: C:\require\require.rb)

```
require "./class.rb"

Henry = Member.new
puts Member.count
```

RESULT: No new member is made, the class is not called, apparently Ruby is looking in different directories (I suppose) even though both filesare right there next to each other in the directory C:\require

(I've set up this whole thing to simplify it, so I can show stack overflow the problem without any unnecessary fluff)

```
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 
 `require': cannot load such file -- ./class.rb (LoadError)
 from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 
 `require'
 from C:/require/require.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

I'm only about 150 hours a developer. I apologize if this is a dumb question but I've exhausted my resources. It seems to work for everybody in every tutorial I watch flawlessly, so I'm quite dumbfounded. Thanks.

P.S. I'm using the Atom text editor (the output comes from pressing Alt + R, for those familiar)

Comment: `require "./class.rb"` → `require_relative "./class.rb"`

Comment: @mudasobwa: Those two should be equivalent...? Or do things work differently on Windows? Wait, does Windows recognise `"./class.rb"`, or does it want `".\\class.rb"`? (In either case, `require_relative "class.rb"` avoids all those problems) (OSX: OP's code works.)

Comment: @Amadan `require` looks up the default path, `.` is not there by default since I believe 1.9 or like.

Comment: @mudasobwa For `require "class.rb"`, yes. For `require "./class.rb"`, no. At least on my system - 2.5.1 on OSX - `require_relative "class.rb"` behaves identically to `require "./class.rb"` (whereas `require "class.rb"` searches `$LOAD_PATH` and fails, since, as you say, `.` is not there any more)

Comment: @Amadan Eh. Indeed.

Comment: But yeah, do try `require_relative 'class.rb'`. Is a good diagnostic.

Comment: You are telling Ruby to look for the file in the current working directory. So, what *is* the current working directory? Obviously, it is not `C:\require`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Indeed, that's very probable, especially since OP is executing it from an editor and might not even know their CWD.

Comment: The current working directory is different from the directory the .rb files are located in? I put both of these sample-for-stack-overflow files right into a directory in C -  C:\require. It's the directory I'm working in - is there something I'm oblivious to? (in this instance - please don't start listing that in general)

Thank you all. 
    `require_relative class.rb ` 
does work. 

    `require class.rb`
still shows the same error message.

Comment: If you are in the same folder and run the code from the same folder this `require_relative 'class'` should workl,  btw dont use `Henry` like local variable.

Comment: @LukasBaliak: If you use `require_relative 'class'`, then it *does not matter at all* what folder you are in and where you run the code from, that is the *whole point* of `require_relative`.

Comment: "The current working directory is different from the directory the .rb files are located in?" – I don't understand what you mean by that. I am asking *you*: is the current working directory `C:\require` or is it something else? Because from the behavior you describe, it looks like the current working directory is *not* `C:\require`, but only you can tell us what the current working directory actually is.

Comment: yes the only reason it seems odd is because I set up the directory and the two files within it for this stack overflow question.
i know require_relative works but there are other files I have downloaded that have deeply embedded requires all over the code - so I was determined to figure out why that code was not working.

Comment: Thanks to all for the help, for now I'll stick to relative_require - perhaps switching over to a linux on windows foundation will help with this quirk. I'm doing so now because I've run into some bugs on rails - windows may indeed be the culprit.